# Referencing the sheet name is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I'm trying to get the sheet name into a cell. I've tried using:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)
```

but my Excel 2003 displays an error when I try to enter the formula. Why is that?

[image]

Could it be because it's excel 2003?

Comment: To isolate which part of your formula is causing the error, try typing "=CELL("filename", A1)" into another cell.

Comment: that part already gives error =CELL("filename", A1)

Comment: @kaze: it seems that EVERY formula that I past is giving me error when it has a "," could that be related to my region being Brazil, or something like that? Or is it necessary to reinstall excel? It really sucks, every formula gives errors in the ",". Is it a problem with excel 2003?

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I must use ";" and not "," between arguments, probably because of some region settings.

Answer (score 1):

An internal sheet reference would look like: **Annual!A1:A10** (where *Annual* is the sheet name obviously).

An external sheet reference would look like: **'C:\Reports[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!A1:A10**

<sub>[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx)</sub>

Comment: @pnuts: His problem turned out to be something else entirely, i.e. his regional settings caused the list separator on his system to be a semicolon instead of a comma, as he found via [a later question](http://superuser.com/questions/579438/excel-gives-error-whenever-i-paste-a-code-with). My answer is correct in terms of the info it provides, just that the OP had another problem entirely.