# Excel gives error whenever I paste a code with ","

Tags: microsoft-excel

My excel is refusing every code that I paste that has "," (comma) (like to separate arguments). What could be the cause, could it be because my PC region is Brazil and excel is in english? It seems to be a system error problem, like it not recognizing the "," as a separator for arguments, something like that. It says like the formula is wrong, but it's not wrong cause others have tried flawlessly, and it always point to something with a ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of your regional settings. Setting the region to Portuguese (Brazil) on English Windows changes many things, in particular:

- The decimal separator is ,
- The list separator is ; (this is a comma when using US English settings)

So the arguments should be separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: Hum so I tought. Is it possible to change the separator to match the default/english?

Comment: I think so, but you will have to change the decimal separator too. Otherwise a number like 3,400 might be three thousand four hundred, or it might be 3 and 400 in a list of two numbers. To change the regional settings see http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-HA010333550.aspx

Comment: I believe it should be inside excel itself not the OS. Is there any configuration like that in excel?

Comment: Thanks pnuts, I've found that option in office 2003 but it doesn't fix the problem in formulas. I still have to use ";", weird.